# Dataframe calculation with condition

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe as mentioned below:

```
DF    Count Count2    %
A     100   0         0%
B     80    20(A-B)  20%
C     50    30(C-C)  37.5%
D     25    25(C-D)  50%
```

For that i have used below code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 100))
df2 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 80))
df3 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 50))
df4 <- data.frame(matrix(nrow = 25))

df <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

count <- c(nrow(df1), nrow(df2), nrow(df3), nrow(df4))

count2 <- vector(mode="numeric", length = 4)

for(i in 1:4) {
  if(i == 1) {
    count2[i] <- 0
  } else {
    count2[i] <- count[i-1] - count[i]
  }
}

percentage <- vector(mode="numeric", length = 4)

for(i in 1:4) {
  if(i == 1) {
    percentage[i] <- 0
  } else {
    percentage[i] <- ((count[i-1] - count[i])/count[i-1]) * 100
  }
}

final_df <- data.frame(df, count, count2, percentage)
```

I want to add a new row betwenn B and C (let say it Z) and for that my count2 formula would be (Count2(B)-Z) instead of (Z-C) and for percentage Count2(Z)/Count2(B).

And Now for C count2 as well as percentage formula would be (B-C) instead of (Z-C).

Desired output:

```
DF    Count Count2            %
A     100   0                 0%
B     80    20(A-B)           20%
Z     15    5 (Count2(B)-Z)   Count2(Z)/Count2(B)
C     50    30(C-C)           37.5%
D     25    25(C-D)           50%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
final_df[5,] <- final_df[4,]
final_df[4,] <- final_df[3,]
levels(final_df[,1]) <- c(levels(final_df[,1]), "Z")
final_df[3,1] <- "Z"
final_df[3,2:4] <- c(15,  final_df[2,3]-15, 100*(final_df[2,3]-15)/final_df[2,3])
```

Comment: Thanks but this workaround couldn't work since my value in Count and Count2 are not static.

Comment: It was not specified in your question .. however, the way to achive it still stands : add a new level, play with index to make a place for the new line, and use indexes to access the needed Count  and Count2 .. what you did not provide also is the origin of "15" as Count for Z .. but i think you will be able to do what you want now ..